# Mailkit - not getting expected exceptions using SendAsync (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, exception, mailkit

If I use the Send method I can process any exceptions as expected.

```
Try
    'Synchronous method
    OutputStatus("Sending message, please wait")
    smtp.Send(mail)

Catch smtpEx As SmtpCommandException
    If smtpEx.ErrorCode = SmtpErrorCode.RecipientNotAccepted Then
        OutputStatus("Unable to send message to: " & smtpEx.Mailbox.Address)
    ElseIf smtpEx.ErrorCode = SmtpErrorCode.UnexpectedStatusCode Then
        OutputStatus("Unable to send message: " & smtpEx.Message)
    ....
    End If
```

However, if I use the SendAsync method I receive no exceptions and the MessageSent event handler does not trigger (so I'm stuck in the Do While loop).
If the message is fine then the event handler works correctly.

```
AddHandler smtp.MessageSent, AddressOf SMTPMessageSent
mbSendingMessage = True
Try
    smtp.SendAsync(mail)

    Do While mbSendingMessage
        Application.DoEvents()
    Loop

Catch ex As Exception
    OutputStatus("Error sending, see GWMailer.err")
End Try

 ....

Private Sub SMTPMessageSent(sender As Object, e As MailKit.MessageSentEventArgs)
    mbSendingMessage = False
End Sub
```

Any help greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just do this?

```
Await smtp.SendAsync(mail)
```

For more information about how to deal with async API's in VB.NET, check out this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/await-operator